# Is there a way to use an NTFS drive that contains my games and is also external to my installation of steam installed viawinetricks?

Tags: partitioning, wine, games, ntfs, steam

I am new to using this site, but not really that new to ubuntu. I decided to do my best to get the things I love to work on linux. I do understand that there are some pretty good games on steam that work natively for linux, unfortunately they aren't my desired games.

First my setup. 
I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
I have 6 hard drives. Each are separate based on the type of files (Games,Application, Movies, Videos, and Ubuntu, and Windows) The Ubuntu drive is only a 40GB hd, and the only ext4 partition. 
Targeted Game DCUO (DC Universe Online)

I know the game actually worked on 12.04, but my problem exist before that. So I mentioned already that my Ubuntu drive is really low on drive space. I am aware I can just buy a new hard drive. But I would like to avoid that for now and get an understanding to my problem.

I wanted to know if it is possible to use an NTFS drive that was normally dedicated for games as a steamapps folder for wine steam. I do not mind reinstalling/deleting/etc the current steamapps that has my windows games.I have a pretty nice upload/download speeds. I just wanted to know of a way to setup steam on wine to also use that ntfs steamapps folder. Or making a new steam apps folder somewhere on one of my drives that has a much bigger capacity because I play a lot of mmo's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly workable and is in fact what I do for my Steam on Wine. The SteamApps folder is shared with the one for Steam on Windows. You can either create a symbolic link (which is how I first used it) or add it properly as a second library folder (which is how I use it now). I haven't had any problems with it. Games installed in Wine show up fine in Windows and vice versa, but you might have to go through the installing/preparing stage once again to get prerequisites.

Comment: Yea it didn't work. But I am just gonna abandon this, and maybe just stick to windows.

Comment: @user306217 that's up to you. What didn't work exactly?